# Update website id using collection

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-collection, save

I have to update website for some items and price. 
I do it in the loop and fetch data from csv file.

I did it this way:

```
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $name)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setPageSize(1)
            ->getFirstItem();
        $product->setWebsiteIds($websiteID);
        $product->setPrice($price);
        $product->setSku($sku);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, "price");
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, "sku");
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, "website_id");
```

The price is updated but I have problem with website_id and sku. I got exception.

in SKU case:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity.value_id' in 'field list' in /var/www/html/cisco/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228

in Website case:

> Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in
>   /var/www/html/cisco/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
>   on line 1548

If I use save() instead of saveAttribute() it works fine but because of the performance I must do it another way.

Could you tell me guys how could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the catalog/product_website model to assign products to websites in bulk.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_website')->addProducts($websiteIds, $productIds);
```